# Route attribute for the home page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The following attribute will route to domain.com/login. How do we use an attribute route for just the domain.com address.

```
// domain.com/login
[Route("Login")]
```

These all fail.

```
// domain.com
[Route("/")]

// domain.com
[Route("~")]
```

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using this:

```
// domain.com
[Route("")]
public ActionResult Index() {}

// domain.com/about
[Route("About")]
public ActionResult AboutUs() {}

// domain.com/login
[Route("Login")]
public ActionResult Login() {}
```